# How can I use a local or external IP address in a program based on which computer is running the program?

Tags: vb.net, client-server, console-application, ip-address, tcp

I'm attempting to design a client-server game using VB.NET console version. The server and client communicate using TCP/IP and port forwarding. I open the server and the client on my computer, and then the other user would open the client on the other end. I've tested this set up using two computers both connected to the same Wi-Fi, and it worked, but it hasn't worked with a friend's computer, I'm assuming because I've got the local IP hard-coded onto both the clients and the server. I've been told that I need to use the external IP for my computer when the client is running on someone else's computer. I'd rather avoid having to make two separate client programs, one with the external and one with the local IP.

So what I want to do is to select my local IP for connection whenever the client is run by this particular computer, and my external IP when it's run by any other computer. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Isn't it better to let the user enter, or at least choose from a list of IPs? Or maybe even save it in a file? Trying to identify which computer your application runs on is just messy.

Comment: If your game has a menu (if not maybe create it), you can add in the menu the option to play in lan or multiplayer! so you can chose if you need local or external IP